# Angular AsyncValidator with debounce and initial value

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I added a debounce to my async validator, there are solutions on SO and Github like this one (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200).

The problem i have is, if the form already has a value when creating all solutions i found do not work.

if the field is empty this one works:

```
return control
    .valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .take(1)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(value => this.systemService.getInstances({ name: value }))
    .map((data) => {
        if (CHECKISTRUE)) {
            return { nameAlreadyExists: true };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

if there is a initial value, control.valueChange is undefined.
My try to fix this issue is:

```
if (!control.valueChanges) {
    return Observable.of(null);
}
```

sadly the status stays PENDING.

all google results lead to a solution for empty fields which does not help.

Comment: Why are you using `take(1)`? This will automatically close the observable after the first emission

Comment: without the status stays PENDING forever: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200#issuecomment-330404820

Comment: I'm having the same problem, an angular form control with initial value and an async validator. the control is always in a PENDING status. did you get to any solution here?

Comment: I forgot about the problem and in which project I had it. but let me check my projects tomorrow, maybe I can find it. I guess the problem was at a complete different part of the code...